# Word and Excel co authoring in SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2016, excel, word, powerpoint, co-authoring

There is a lot of confusion on this topic so I just want to confirm if following is true:

Word = Supports co-authoring via both desktop application and Office Online Server/Office Web App Server

Powerpoint = Supports co-authoring via both desktop application and Office Online Server/Office Web App Server

Excel = Only support co-authoring via Office Online Server/Office Web App Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint 2016 on-premise only supports co-authoring with Word and PowerPoint. Co-authoring with Excel desktop or even web-based client (through Office Web Apps Server) is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [Feature availability across Office Online plans](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office-online-service-description.aspx) for a comparison list. All mentioned apps support real time co-authoring via browser and desktop app (Word, Excel, PowerPoint).

More information especially about Excel can be found in 
[Collaborate on Excel workbooks at the same time with co-authoring](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Collaborate-on-Excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104)

Comment: As per this thread, Excel support is very limited or actually non-existent when using SharePoint on-premise. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82de1cb4-3011-4545-b847-32f364883a34/word-and-excel-coauthoring-in-sharepoint-2016